# SharePoint column values contain extra ;# characters 

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007

There's this bug that interferes with the output of data at my Silverlight 2.0 control. When users for eg., select a user from a SharePoint 2007 column field **Person or Group**, the output will be displayed as:

- `9;#Carol` or
- `string;#4/8/2011` (column field **Date and Time**)

How may I eliminate the additional characters passed in then?
Hotfixes didn't help much either.

Answer (score 2):

the `;#` is SharePoint's data separator.  Its similar to a comma in a Comma Separated Values (CSV) file.  You'll need to parse the data manually:

```
string[] parsedData = data.Split(new string[] { ";#" });
```

In the case of the `Person or Group` field, the `9` is the User ID of the user.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Sir. Solved the issue anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the problem lies with my source code, just edit it to the following:

```
return value.Substring(value.LastIndexOf(";#") + 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `split` function. You should use `SPFieldUserValue` as shown in this post

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/94c04deb-c7d1-426f-bb2f-5c894457e2b6/

Comment: Using MOSS2007 in a Silverlight control, `Microsoft.SharePoint.dll` isn't available, so `SPFieldUserValue` would not be available either.

Comment: @Kyle: This is not valid. You can always add reference to Microsoft.SharePoint.dll even in a Silverlight control. What's stopping you from doing that? If silverlight control is deployed in SharePoint server, the reference will always work